# Schlumberger Eclipse 100 Simulation, constraint the reservoir pressure?

Tags: petrel

I am trying to put a limitation on the reservoir pressure so it doesnt go above a certain amount let's say 4000 PSIA

So when I do the injection, and then the production will decline, the pressure will increase, once it hits a value the run will terminate

Would you please suggest a way to do that?
Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone helped me out with the answer, so I hope my answer will help someone else

```
ACTIONX
ACT1 4060 /
FPR > 4060 /
/

END
ENDACTIO
```